# Microsoft Teams Graph API does not support sending Microsoft Teams invite

Tags: api, graph, microsoft-teams, invite, microsoft-graph-teams

I cannot figure out how to add a member to a Microsoft Teams team that I clone. Any assistance here would be much appreciated.

I created a Microsoft Teams Team with myself as the owner. The member user does not appear in Teams if programmatically created and assigned.

The steps to create the member user is as follows. 
1.  Creates a user in active directory using the Create Invitation via the Microsoft Graph API 
2.  Test Add Group Member via the Microsoft Graph API

The following Microsoft Graph queries return the user created in active directory and in the group.
1.  List Active Directory Users via the Microsoft Graph API
2.  List the members in a Teams group via the Microsoft Graph API.

Below you will find my code and screenshots..

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    object data = new
    {
        invitedUserEmailAddress = "sean_dorsett@hotmail.com",
        inviteRedirectUrl = "https://teams.microsoft.com/",
        sendInvitationMessage = true
    };

    var defaultRequetHeaders = client.DefaultRequestHeaders;
    if (defaultRequetHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequetHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
    defaultRequetHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", result.AccessToken);

    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations", byteContent);
    var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    string jsonData = "{\"@odata.id\":\"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{guid}\"}";
    buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
    byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response = await client.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{guid}/members/$ref", byteContent);
    contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

[Active Directory User Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyrMc.jpg)

[Active Directory Groups Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnVk.jpg)

[Microsoft Teams Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr1a8.jpg)

[Microsoft Teams Group Member Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6ERw.jpg)

Comment: I did find an article describing a workaround, but the API method is throwing a 404. I am going to guess that it was deprecated.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3759

https://api.teams.skype.com/emea/beta/teams/$($teamurl)/bulkUpdateRoledMembers?allowBotsInChannel=true

Comment: Could you please try this [sample code](https://gist.github.com/chenxizhang/48642a33334883ee381d448e0cbe0b9d)?